# Angular form is undefined when submitting via ngSubmit

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, single-page-application, angular8

I have a form outlined in my app.component.html file as below, when I click the Send button to submit the form I get an error in my Javascript saying that the chatForm is undefined.

I've had a look at a few different tutorials and I can't seem to find why this function is not operating as I expect. What am I doing wrong?

Also when I'm submitting the form how do I get the value of the input that is present in my form? I have a name of `message` defined on the form, how can I use this variable?

app.component.html

```html
<div class="container">
    <h2>Message Form</h2>
    <form (ngSubmit)="sendMessage(chatForm)" #chatForm="ngForm">
        <div>
            <label for="message">Message</label>
            <input type="text" id="message" name="message" [(ngModel)]="message" required>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" id="sendmessage" [disabled]="!chatForm.valid">
            Send
        </button>
    </form>
</div>
```

app.component.ts

```js
public sendMessage(form): void {
    console.log("Message sent: " + form.value);
}
```

Comment: Do you have `@ViewChild('chatForm') form` defined in app.component.ts?

Comment: @Viqas I don't, where should this be defined?

Comment: No need to use ViewChild

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should get the data by using

```
form.value.message
```

My example look like this

```html
  <form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(registerForm)" #registerForm="ngForm">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="UserName">Your email</label>
      <input
        type="text"
        ngModel
        class="form-control"
        id="UserName"
        name="UserName"
        required
      />
```

Then in my component I can access to the form data like this

```js
onSubmit(formValue: NgForm) {
    const registerModel: AccountModel = {
      UserName: formValue.value.UserName,
      Password: formValue.value.Password
    };
```

Comment: I've edited my code and it now works and submits correctly, thanks! There's a few different things I added, so I'm not sure which one was causing the error. Was it because I wasn't defining `formValue: NgForm` in my function? Or was it because I was lacking `form-group` and `form-control` in my HTML? Or was it because I had `[(ngModel)] = message` instead of just `ngModel`?

Comment: I think the error come from your ```[(ngModel)] = message``` because you are using 2 way binding